# How to call focus to an element after the window was loaded?

Tags: xul

In Xul, how to call focus to an element after the window was loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page on [Focus and Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Focus_and_Selection) and this one [On page load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load) should help you out, I think.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){document.getElementById('ele-id').focus()}, false);
```

If the element is not focusable by default, then make it so with:

```
style="-moz-user-focus: normal;"
```

Make sense?

Comment: I had forgoten the `document.` part when getting the element by id. In some parts it's not needed.. sad.. Thanks!